# Are there drawbacks to altering MySQL table data types?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering that how much worried I should be about data types. I can easily jump from TINYINT to SMALLINT and from SMALLINT to INT, but are there any drawbacks to this? Obviously situations like from text to int will have consequences, but I'm talking about situations like INT->BIGINT, TINYTEXT->TEXT, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to a "larger" version of the data type should be harmless. The only "drawback" of course would be that the column requires more storage space. But this shouldn't be a deal breaker unless you have a massive table.

Just be sure to check your foreign keys before you make a change like that. Foreign keys must have the same type (even down to specific attributes like `UNSIGNED`)